# Need SQL query to find count

Tags: sql, aggregate

```
Household          Individual
101                      11
101                      12
101                      13
101                      14
101                      15
102                      1
102                      2
102                      3
102                      4
```

I need a SQL query to get the number of households with more than 4 individuals. In the above table, only household `101` has more than 4 individuals. So the extract should be `1`.

Comment: first, there are many different SQL out there, which you are you using? MYSQL? Second, `So here the extract should be 1.` do you mean 101? your description and your expected results seems to conflict with each other, can you clarify? Lastly, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
    SELECT Household 
    FROM   TableName 
    GROUP BY Household 
    HAVING COUNT(Household) > 4
) AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Household)
FROM
(
 SELECT Household
 FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY Household
 HAVING Count(Household) > 4
) Tmp
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3d8a/4)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Household, count(Household) as cnt FROM {{TABLE}} 
GROUP BY Household
WHERE cnt > 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT household FROM YourTable
GROUP BY household
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT individual) > 4
```

Comment: OP wants the count of this result set.

Comment: I showed how to obtain these records, it counts the number of trivial

Comment: @realnumber3012: Agreed. I took the same approach initially...but then considered that the OP's difficulty may (in part) hinge on simply selecting from a subquery. Still, a valid point I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should give you the right value (1).

```
select count(*) from (select Household  from table group by Household  having count(*)>4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    distinct Household
from 
    Table_2
where
    Individual > 4
```

Result will be 101.

If you need count (not number as above), then

```
select 
    COUNT (Household) as E1
from 
    Table_2
where
    Individual > 4
```

Comment: This is not correct because `Individual` column shows the ID of each individual.

Answer (score 0):

### Initial Answer

Of course a demonstration requires choosing a SQL implementation, my choice being T-SQL; but the solution is pretty generalizable to other SQL implementations:

```
declare @householdInfo table (Household int, Individual int);

insert into @householdInfo (Household, Individual)
select 101, 11
union
select 101, 12
union
select 101, 13
union
select 101, 14
union
select 101, 15
union
select 102, 1
union
select 102, 2
union
select 102, 3
union
select 102, 4;

--select * from @householdInfo; -- FORNOW: for sanity checking

-- NOTE: what you basically need - that yields 1 like you expect
select COUNT(*)
from (
    select Household, COUNT(Individual) IndividualCount
    from @householdInfo
    group by Household
    having COUNT(Individual) > 4) s;
```

The important parts are that you need to:

1. Select the `COUNT`s of `Individual`s in the inner query.
2. Group the `COUNT`s of `Individual`s on `Household` values.
3. Use the aggregate equivalent of `WHERE` - `HAVING` - to filter the inner query's results (i.e. `> 4`).
4. Select the final `COUNT` in the outer query.

### Follow-On

@VigneshKumar and @GiannisParaskevopoulos make a good point - that you technically do not need `COUNT` in the inner query's column list.

Another (ugly) subtlety exists in the wild, may apply to your situation, and necessitates not only `COUNT(Individual)` in the inner query('s `HAVING` clause) but further leveraging a *distinct count*:

```
select COUNT(Household) -- yes, prefer Household over * for clarity
from (
    select Household
    from @householdInfo
    group by Household
    -- distinct added if duplicates are an issue
    having COUNT(distinct Individual) > 4) s;
```

A simple change from the sample data you provided to...

```
Household    Individual
---------    ----------
101          11
101          12
101          13
101          14
101          15
102          1
102          2
102          3
102          4
102          4 -- NOTE: duplicate row to demonstrate the point
```

...makes the distinction (pun intended) clear (i.e. that the 1st query I provided would yield 2 in this case whereas the 2nd query I provided would still yield 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(Household) AS HouseholdsWithMoreThan4Individuals
FROM (
    SELECT Household
    FROM [MytTable]
    GROUP BY Household
    HAVING COUNT(Individual) > 4) Res;
```

In this case the result will be 1 - the result you require - because there is only one household with more than 4 individuals.

You need to perform two operations: first you need to get a list of all households with more than 4 individuals. After that you need to count those households. You need to be careful not to count any household more than once.